# enabled filter not working properly - Opencart

Tags: opencart

I have installed and enabled filter option , it is not displayed. From my searches it is found that there is a **Add module** button. but it is not found in my admin page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all You need to set position for modules. Read this tutorial for How to enabled module in OpenCart 2. http://www.harnishdesign.net/blog/2014/10/09/how-to-set-layout-position-of-module-in-opencart-2-0/

also, Follow following steps for add product filter in module.

1. Go to Catalog > Filters and select Insert to create a filter group. Assign a filter group name (e.g. Color) and add filter name values (e.g. Blue, Red, Yellow).
2. Go to Catalog > Categories and Edit a category. Under the Data tab add the filters you want to be able to apply to that category (e.g. Color > Blue, Color > Red).
3. Go to Catalog > Products and Edit a product. Under the Links tab add the filters which apply to the product (e.g. Color > Blue). Apply to as many products as applicable.
4. Go to Extensions > Modules > Filter. If not installed select Install. Click Edit. Click the Add Module button and under Layout select Category and set Status to Enabled. Set whatever position and sort order you would like.